# Set Dropdown List with value after first dropdown list change is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with rows and each column contains a dropdownlist.  Once the value is selected in the first dropdown list , the second one is populated with values based on what they selected wit the first dropdownlist.

I am looping throw the rows and correctly manually setting the value on the first dropdown list , however after when i go to set the second dropdownlist its not working.  I am wondering if its a wait issue or something else.

```
   $('.usergroup tr').each(function (i) {

       if (i > 2 && i != tableRowsCount) {
           var amountTextBox = $(this).find(':input[type=text]');
           amountTextBox.val(data.items[i - 3].amount);
           var column1 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)");
           var groupddl = column1.find('select');
           groupddl.val(data.items[i - 3].highLevelAggregation).change();

           //  if (data.items[i-3].midLevelAggregation !== 'undefined' && data.items[i-3].midLevelAggregation !== null) {
           var column2 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)");
           var groupdd2 = column2.find('select');
           groupdd2.attr('selectedIndex', 2).change();

           // }
           //   });
           //if (data.items[i - 3].id !== 'undefined' && data.items[i - 3].id !== null) {
           // var column3 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)");
           //  var groupdd3 = column3.find('option:nth-child(2)').val();
           //  groupdd3.val(data.items[i - 3].id).change();
           //}
       }
  });
```

Not setting anything on the second dropdownlist

Comment: repro of the problem could help others debug the issue. can you please use jsbin or codepen to put this code?

Comment: @adam here is a jsfiddle with an example https://jsfiddle.net/6e3pdryw/223/ hope it helps

Comment: mine is a little different because the second dropdown list gets populated based on what you selected for option 1

Comment: there was another event calling the change event that was rebinding to the dropdownlist